# Adding users in Sharepoint

Tags: user-profile, sharepoint-online

How do you add users in Sharepoint Online without importing from AD?  I've seen a few places mention you can do it but when I create and save a user it complains it doesn't match a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regularly it should be 2 different types of "users" - those coming from AD (primary) and external users  - for those that do not have/require a license. For the externals you would basically send out invitations they would accept and get access to the SharePoint site.

[Update #1 ] This link actually explains the concepts http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/share-a-site-with-external-users-HA102476183.aspx

Comment: So there's no way of creating content editors without AD other than the user I set up during account creation?

Comment: no, actually external users can collaborate once they got their invitation. of course prior to being able to invite someone you would need to activate the feature to allow external users, they respond and associate their email with a Microsoft account after which you can assign permissions. see more here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/share-a-site-with-external-users-HA102476183.aspx

Comment: Hmmm... I'd tried that but it wouldn't seem to let me in without a MS Live login.  Will give it another go, maybe I missed a step.  Thanks.

Comment: @C.Marius the link you provided seems dead.

Comment: I did a new search and got this link: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/share-a-site-with-external-users-HA102476183.aspx?CTT=1 (`?CTT=1` was added to the link)